# How can I create a shape tween that follows a specified morphing path in Flash CS5?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, shapes, tween, spiral

I am trying to start with a circle and have that circle gradually become a spiral, but I only want the shape to tween from the end of the spiral, rather than the whole shape itself, is there a way to do this without frame by frame animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research I have discovered that the only way to do this is by using tweening hints. These can be accessed from the `insert` menu or by pressing `ctrl + shift + h`